# Почему не работает код?Хочу ограничить вертикальный поворот камеры(Unity)

Tags: unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensitivity = 9.0f;
    public float yAngle = 0;
    public float xAngle = 0;
    void Update()
    {
        xAngle -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;
        yAngle += Mathf.Clamp(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity, -45, 45);
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(xAngle, yAngle, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратите внимание на строчку

```
yAngle += Mathf.Clamp(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity, -45, 45);
```

Заменяя оператор `+=` это можно записать так

```
 yAngle = yAngle + Mathf.Clamp(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity, -45, 45);
```

Таким образом с помощью `Mathf.Clamp` вы удерживаете в границах -45...+45 только дельту, но не само значение.

Что бы это исправить нужно заключить всё выражение в `Mathf.Clamp`, например так:

```
 yAngle = Mathf.Clamp(yAngle + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity,-45, 45);
```

Кроме того, с высокой долей вероятности, вертикальной у вас будет ось Х.

Вот код, который позволяет ограничивать вращение камеры в двух измерениях:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mouseLook  : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float sensitivity = 9.0f;
    public float yAngle = 0;
    public float xAngle = 0;
    public float yAngleVariation = 45f; //Change it
    public float xAngleVariation = 45f; //Change it

    void Update()
    {
        xAngle = Mathf.Clamp(xAngle - Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity,-xAngleVariation,xAngleVariation);
        yAngle = Mathf.Clamp(yAngle + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity,-yAngleVariation,yAngleVariation);
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(xAngle, yAngle, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как верный. Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ отмечен как решение вопроса. Вы можете в любой момент снять галку или отметить ею другой ответ.